# How to keep formulas working when copy and pasting in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way in formulas, other than creating an extra column, to reference the first cell of a table such that I can copy and paste the table and the formulas still work?

`=VLOOKUP($A$1, $E$1:$F$12, 2, 0)` for `B2:B8`

```
Name1      Rate
Sunday     0.1
Monday     0.1
Tuesday    0.1
Wednesday  0.1
Thursday   0.1
Friday     0.1
Saturday   0.1
Sunday     0.1
```

Name1 is A1.

This should be enough but just in case example is at this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19z-LLTj4pcvDCUaoq72qcBicHsT1Gq5Z9i8haPLRIsI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Not actually sure what does your "formulas still work" mean, but hope it helps. In your example, you use an absolute reference to cells. You can spot it by "$" signs before column name and row number. If you delete those signs - your references will become relative ones. More on the topic can be found [HERE](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excelformulas/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/).

**UPD.** So, you need a mix of absolute and relative references. Here is how it could be done. Put this into your B2 cell as a **single cell array formula** (Ctrl+Shift+Enter). Spread it for the first table - and you are ready to copy it anywhere:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX((B$1:B1="Rate")*ROW($A$1:A1));COLUMN()-1));$E$1:$F$12;2;0)
```

It works by searching for the latest row with the "Rate" header. So make sure it is always present. If your header may change - you might be interested in a user-defined formula on VBA.

`$A$1:A1` is not important since it's needed only to get numbers for different rows. `$E$1:$F$12` is your fixed table.

Comment: I do understand absolute versus relative references. The issue with making these relative is the formula is vunerable if the table extends downwards and requires editing every cell. If you're unsure what OP is asking you can ask as a comment.

Comment: "You can aks as a comment" - available starting with 50 reputation points.

Comment: my bad - I forgot about that "feature"

Comment: I've found a solution and edited my initial post. Pls check if it solves your task.

Comment: I got you @RomanVoronov. Someone else give this man a click so he can join the world of **COMMENTS**!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exactly what you're looking for but piecing together your verbiage to form the question: "*Is it possible to reference the first cell of a table?*"

Yes!

You can use **Index** with 1,1 and the Table name. See below example with a sample table called **Table1** and the formula to pull the value in the first row and column `=INDEX(Table1,1,1)`. If you wanted the headers, you could modify the formula to read: `=INDEX(Table1[#Headers],1,1)` which would return "MOND".

Again, probably not what you're looking for, but if anyone does a search, they might find this useful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have an option to Copy paste formulas, but the think is that you have to freeze your Formulas properly.

you have Freeze completely **$A$1** cell, and copied the same for all which is completely incorrect. You have freeze it as **$A1** 
Corrected Example of your formula : **=VLOOKUP($A1, $E$1:$F$12, 2, 0)**

The freeze means crating relative cell reference.

Please refer the below link to know about **Relative and Absolute Cell Reference** completely.

**https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/11/25/relative-absolute-reference-excel/**

Answer (score 0):

In end I decided to go with extra column but an example of formula allowing a table to be copied to a different column.

`{=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()-1, 4), "1", "")&MIN(IF(OFFSET(L:L, 0, -1)<>"", ROW(OFFSET(L:L, 0, -1)), 9999999)))}`

**Broken down**

- `SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()-1, 4)` gets column letter string of column one to left, so if we are in column `L:L` this would return `"K"`. Would need to amend `COLUMN()-1` to `COLUMN()-2`, `COLUMN()-3` etc for other columns
- `OFFSET(L:L, 0, -1)` returns `K:K`.
- `MIN(IF(OFFSET(L:L, 0, -1)<>"", ROW(OFFSET(L:L, 0, -1)), 9999999))`

is equivalent to

- `MIN(IF(K:K<>"", ROW(K:K), 9999999))` which returns row number of first non-empty cell in column `K:K`
- Formula is array formula

This works provided that:

1. Table does not share columns with original.
2. Nothing is above the tables in question.